# Python doesn't convert string list into regular list?

Tags: python, list

I have a string ouput which looks like below

```
result = "[(u'Delhi', 20199330), (u'Mumbai', 134869470), (u'Kolkata', 6678446)]"
```

Now I want to convert it to a regular array. So this is what I do

```
import json

print(json.loads(result))
```

But I get the following error

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Now I know `result` is not  a `json`. But python does convert a string list into a regular list by doing something like

```
some_list = "[10, 20, 30]"

print(json.loads(some_list))
```

So I was hoping it would convert my `result` which is a string list of tuples into a regular list of tuples. But it throws error.

How can I convert `result` into a regular list?

Comment: use `ast` module--> `ast.literal_eval(result)`

Comment: @souvik-ray that's Python, not JSON

Comment: I would be more concerned how you ended up with a string representation of a Python literal in the first place…

Comment: @deceze its the output of a Postgres database.

Comment: How did this get *into* the database in the first place…?

Comment: bet someone thought doing `str(some_list)` is how jsons are made. PS. its wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> result = "[(u'Delhi', 20199330), (u'Mumbai', 134869470), (u'Kolkata', 6678446)]"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(result)
[('Delhi', 20199330), ('Mumbai', 134869470), ('Kolkata', 6678446)]
```